# Left mouse button on a touchpad stops working after lid is closed

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, laptop

I use Ubuntu (20.04) on an ASUS UX330UK laptop. The left mouse button on a touchpad stops working after lid is closed.

However, if I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login again into the system, everything works fine.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i have same thing - some drivers on ubuntu (like this from mouse/touchpad) are starting AFTER login (when window manager is started)- if your touchpad have also physical keys, they will work cause they're detected as regular mouse buttons. to fix it you'll need to find executable for divers and execute them in terminal with `@reboot` before their filename. hope it helps =)

Comment: You seem to offer a solution. But I doubt that this very compact wording could help anyone to succesfully follow the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing for me since Ubuntu 20.04 installed. That was bothering me for a while. Solution is to install Gnome Tweaks. Go to "General" setting and disable "Suspend when laptop lid is closed".